# Unix command in informatica

Tags: informatica

My Requirement is to get source counts,target counts and the rows that did not get changed that gets loaded via informatica.(Example:: Source::100, Target::50,Ignored(No change)::50)
I need to achieve this using presession and postsession command task.Can anyone help me with the scripts.

Thanks for the help in Advance

Comment: Try to do it yourself first and let us know where you are facing problem. It is not the right forum to provide complete solution to your requirement.

Comment: This might come in handy: http://powercenternotes.blogspot.com/2014/01/an-etl-framework-for-operational.html

Comment: first, let us know what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

try to grep the information from the session log which gets created for every run. If you are still looking for the script, let me know.

example :

if you go to the bottom of the session log you see session load summary like below

## SESSION LOAD SUMMARY

## Output Rows [44768], Affected Rows [44768], Applied Rows [44768], Rejected Rows [0]

do cat log file name | grep 'Output Rows' in post session command

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Your answer as it stands is more like a comment. You should probably post an example of what you mean to be considered an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the metadata tables, write a Unix script on the infa server to get the count of `SuccessfulRow` count and all other counts you want from it and call it using `postsession cmd` which will also help you build an alert mechanism in for the number of count you get using `mail -x`. just see the below illustration.

Let me know if you need more details on this.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you can see where you can add details to the answer, it is safer to just [edit] and add them, instead of waiting for the OP to ask. The main reason for this is because you're not just answering one person - you're answering everyone who will find this question and answer.

Comment: So should provide the whole code how to build this?

Comment: Not necessarily the whole code. The way I recommend approaching an answer is asking yourself "if I only knew enough to have the problem described in the question, and I found this answer via Google, what would I want to know?" How much to include is rather subjective, and I don't know what an idea answer for this would look like (I don't know informatica). However, anytime I feel like I should include something like "Let me know if you need more details" in one of my answers, that's a clue to me that I may not have given sufficient detail. So, I'm just advising in general here.

Comment: Yeah got that. Thanks for those comments will keep in my mind, I'll update the comment asap I get a generic terms on how to build that Unix script for this

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer:  Refer to REP_SESS_Logs table in Informatica metadata repository Database.